# How to fix a terminal after a binary file has been dumped inside it?

Tags: terminal

After having played with curl, a binary file has been dumped inside my terminal. For example, the horizontal lines: ─ I use to format my prompt are replaced by 'q', and it can be much worse.

Why does this happen, and how can you fix it without having to close the terminal
?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think `reset` would definitely fix it.

Consider looking into [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/reset).

Example:

```
[m0nhawk@terra:~]> cat /dev/urandom
êIÉè;┤Ü)MåÇ▐¿÷¢§ôWdO┘&!π¡
[└█┼░▒┬┐@├err▒:·]> c▒├ /de┴/┤r▒┼do└
```

And `reset`fixes this.

Comment: Worth to mention, if you run `cat /dev/urandom`, abort with Ctrl-C. Also, @Antoine, you could examine `clear`. I know you said "terminal", but, in the Linux console, there is (besides `clear` and `reset`) `clear_console` as well.

Comment: In some cases, `reset` has been known not to solve this. `echo -e '\017'` can help there.

Comment: "some cases" basically refers to those where the terminal description is incorrect.

Comment: reset does more than that, it resets everything to defaults.
Afterward you might find yourself in a terminal with unusable "width"  
The mentioned "stty sane" command does the job better

Comment: In many cases echo -e '\017' is the solution like Alexios said, most other suggested commands like reset or stty can do more harm than good.

Comment: when I'm connected over SSH (I use Bitvise) only Alexios solution fixes for me `echo -e '\017'`, nothing else would work

Answer (score 10):

Typing the command `stty sane` should fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Best solution I've found is:

```
echo <ctrl-v><esc>c<enter>
```

I alias this to "unbinary"

Comment: For a terminal *emulator*, sure.  But a full reset on a hardware terminal (or serial connection) is a little drastic (you would have to log in again).

Comment: worked for me when `stty sane` did nothing & reset changed width to default and still had a wierd char