# Fix terminal after displaying a binary file

Tags: terminal, console, fonts, binary

I'd tried command `cat` with an executable file:

```
cat /bin/ls
```

Now I can't read any word in this terminal (Linux console). How can I fix it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, maybe your terminal is screwed; try typing `reset`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix a terminal after a binary file has been dumped inside it?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50752/how-to-fix-a-terminal-after-a-binary-file-has-been-dumped-inside-it)

Comment: Actually I think the answer's here are better, so better mark as dup the other way

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Often times when in a Unix/Linux terminal (Bash) for example you'll use the commands `more` or `less` or `cat` to view a file. When you do this and the file isn't meant to be viewed (such as `/bin/ls`) you'll get output like this:

[image: ss of binary output]

What's going on here is that you just tried to view a file that's a program. An executable which aren't meant to be viewed with standard viewers as I mentioned above.

#### method #1 - reset

To fix this issue you can do the following:

1. Hit Control + C a couple of times (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
2. Type the command `reset` and hit return

This should usually put your terminal back into a more normal  mode. I'll mention one more thing, when you do the steps above, you'll by typing them blind into your terminal. So just make sure you're typing it correctly.

#### method #2 - stty sane

As suggested in the comments by @sendmoreinfo you might have better luck using the following commands instead if the above doesn't work:

```
$ stty sane
$ tput rs1
```

#### determining a files' type

Incidentally, if you come across a file and aren't sure if it's going to mess up your terminal you can inspect the file using the command `file` which will report back the type of file it is.

For example, with `/bin/ls` that file shows the following output:

```
$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped
```

Comment: `reset` is not a 100% cure for terminal madness.  Try `stty sane` followed by `tput rs1`.

Comment: @sendmoreinfo - thanks I've added your suggestion to the answer. I'd used `stty sane` but never `tput`.

Comment: actually, I need to research this more.  reset is supposed to send rs1 string.  A good test (for xterm, at least) is to make cursor invisible and see if reset brings it back.

Comment: `reset` worked in my case

Comment: `clear` also works for mild cases.

Comment: Oddly enough, i've just tried to `cat /bin/ls` - and when it finished, my terminal was OK. Then, i triet `cat /etc/localtime`, which garbled my terminal, but right after that i have executed `cat /bin/sh`, which restored it to it's original glory. Weird.

Comment: I tested *stty sane*, and it did't work, but *tput rs1* worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 56):

I've had an occasion where none of the usual tricks, `reset` or `stty sane`, worked (after accidentally calling `print` on a python bytearray). I had success with [method 2 listed on this helpful blog](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-fix-the-display.html).

I've since created a most helpful alias:

```
alias fix='echo -e "\033c"'
```

Comment: I know this is old, but this is the only answer above that worked for me! Thanks

Comment: This `echo -e "\033c"` helped me to clean up a character-garbled SSH login terminal session that was mixed up after a `cat /etc/localtime`.

Comment: This worked with OpenBSD, when all others did not.

Comment: this re-broke my terminal. Im using screen(1). It seems it contracts a 'virus' from the binary file display -- reset doesn't fix it, stty sane re-breaks it -- only xterm's "do full reset" works - but if I switch to another screen window, it rebreaks the display. Even using all 4 methods doesnt work (reset, sane, tput, echo \033c).

I can destroy my entire screen session but I really don't want to.

Comment: further experimentation with screen(1) found force detatching of all sessions (-D) then issuing the reset commands to the underlying terminal screen was run in, could fix the issue. may also need to rename corrupted window names that may re-display the same binary data at the terminal causing it to corrupt (and then reset yet again).

Comment: My terminal size ( LINES ) was cut in roughly half after using vi while  connecting to the console of a remote linux host via SOL.   The remote session had LINES=24 whereas my local MAC session had LINES=51.   echo -e "\033c" worked for me but none of the other fixes I tried did ( 'stty sane', tput rs1 , tput sgr0, reset ).

Comment: Isn't this the same as pressing `Alt-C` (equivalent to `ESC C`)?

Comment: echo -e will add a new line, use printf instead

Answer (score 18):

No single prior answer worked for me. But this seemed to do the trick in .bashrc add:

```
alias fix='reset; stty sane; tput rs1; clear; echo -e "\033c"'
```

and then when the problem occurs type this (even though you probably can't see it!)

```
(ctl-c, ctl-c, ctl-c)
fix
```

Much thanks to the prior submitters. Also, as a side note, the reason that your terminal goes wonky when showing those executable files (or keystores, etc) is that those files often contain binary sequences that are control codes. The control codes may do random things like switch to a graphics character set, set foreground and background colors to the same thing, etc.

Comment: Same happened. Nothing worked for me, just this combo...

Comment: I called my `sane`

Answer (score 6):

I have almost the same alias as the previous post, with one small change (`tput reset` instead of `rs1`) and one added command (`setterm -reset`):

```
alias clr='echo -e "\033c" ; stty sane; setterm -reset; reset; tput reset; clear'
```

Answer (score 5):

`tmux` users might be able to send all these commands to their shell, but the resetting doesn't get elevated to the `tmux` pane.

Make new tmux window:
`ctrl-B c`
`tmux list-panes`
Note the pane number you think is borked, typically `0`. Let's call it `PPP`

Select the tmux window, where `XXX` is the window number which is borked, not necessarily the same as pane number.
`ctrl-B XXX`
`tmux send-key -R -t PPP`

You will then see all the commands in the other answers to this question which made it to your shell, but didn't work! Maybe a blind `tmux send-key -R -t PPP` will work, but I can't test.

Answer (score 5):

I know this has been here a while, but while many of the other answers have worked for me, reset, stty sane, sometimes neither of those has worked for me and I always resort to:

```
echo ^v^o
```

That's echo Ctrl+V followed by Ctrl+O

Comment: this does the trick for me on a remote SSH session using the bitvise terminal

Answer (score 3):

Nothing above helped me. However, Jack Wasey mentioned tmux, so I just ran `tmux`, exited again and everything was back to normal.

Another solution is:

```
reset
```

Comment: Only running `tmux` and exiting worked for me. No other thing mentioned on this page.
(My exact problem was: under WSL in default terminal window (not Terminal!) mouse commands were generating escape sequences that were not interpreted, i.e.: `2;53;18M2;53;18m`.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers advising how to reset the terminal, I figured the corruption cannot be avoided unless properly guarded.  So I better send the output to a simple text-friendly converter `cat -v`:

```
docker logs myjenkinscontainer 2>&1 | cat -v
```

Viewing and editing binary files seems possible with `hexdump -C` and `vi -R` (`:%!xxd -g1` for a hex view and `:%!xxd -g1 -r` for saving hex changes).

Comment: It took a while to learn that termcap/terminfo's are for applications. That is, they are terminals' "user manuals" and do not protect the terminal against their interpreting escape and control characters sent by applications that disregard visualization concerns. Luckily there is a layer in between, `tmux`, along with its option to avoid translating for the underlying terminal (and drop!) the special characters sent by applications to its virtual `screen` driver, `set-option -ga terminal-overrides ',*:enacs@:smacs@:rmacs@:acsc@'`.  The option works in recent versions of `tmux` such as `2.3`.

Answer (score 0):

This garbled terminal mode is called Alternate Character Set , ACS for short.

to get out of it:

```
$ tput sgr0             # stop all special effects, including ACS

$ setterm --default     # equivalent
$ setterm --reverse=off # equivalent
```

or

```
$ tput rmacs       # stop ACS
```

to start ACS:

```
$ tput smacs       # start  ACS
```

on some terminals you need to not only start it but also enable it:

```
$ tput enacs smacs   # enable and start ACS, only some terminals require this
```

if your terminal also has other defects like colors, background, bold, italic, blink, ... :

```
$ tput sgr0        # disable all special effects, including ACS

# you can experiment with these control sequences:
$ tput bold       # bold/bright
$ tput rev        # reverse mode
$ tput setaf 1    # set foreground color to red [0-7]
$ tput setab 3    # set background color to yellow [0-7]
$ tput bold setaf 1 setab 3    # combined sequence
```

**recommended** :
if you want to never have to worry about these defects in your working environment, you can integrate the reset sequence into you prompt, at the appropriate place in your init script/config like this:

```
# in init script , for example ~/.bash_profile
export PS1='\['`tput sgr0`'\] \u@\h \w \$ '

# or prompt with colors and reset at the end
export PS1=' \[\e[37m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\[\e[32m\]\h \[\e[37m\]\W \$ \['`tput sgr0`
```

other commands that could influence it:

```
# the following two enable/disable ACS, the effects are reversed on some terminals
# these sometimes interact with tput smacs/rmacs in wierd ways
$ echo ^V^O    # echo Ctrl-V,Ctrl-O,Enter
$ echo ^V^N
```

more ways to stop ACS, also clears the screen:

```
$ echo -e '\ec'                  #
$ echo -e '\033c'                # these 3 are equivalent
$ echo <ctrl-v><esc><c>          #

$ reset                 #
$ tput rs1              # rs2/rs3
$ tput reset            #          don't work on some terminals
$ setterm --reset       #
$ setterm --initialize  #
```

if you want to inspect the control sequences, which are different on different terminals:

```
$ tput sgr0 | cat -v
$ tput sgr0 | od -c    # or od -ca for more representations 
$ infocmp
```

more info in the man pages for terminfo, setterm, infocmp, tput, cat, od