# Ran ifconfig, everything formatted weird now

Tags: ifconfig

As a beginner to *nix, I was looking (not editing) at system files on my Apple laptop. I looked at ipconfig (with `cat`) and suddenly everything is formatted weirdly, even when I `ls` ordinary directories. Does anyone know what I may have done, and how to get it back to normal?

Comment: Show an example please

Comment: Maybe you ran `cat` on the ifconfig binary?

Comment: See [Fix terminal after displaying a binary file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79684/88378); also http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-4.html may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Type "reset" in the command prompt. You might have to do it blindly. Also see:

[Fix terminal after displaying a binary file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79684/fix-terminal-after-displaying-a-binary-file)