# Reset cursor state without reopening terminal

Tags: terminal

When using an application that have an anormal tui, or print non-supported characters/terminal sequence, it usually happen that the cursor/terminal doesn't display right.

In those moment, i usually do `clear && reset` but while that work, it doesn't *work* for resetting the cursor in it's usual state, unless i close and reopen the terminal (happen on most terminal i tried this on, xterm, st, urxvt etc)

I tried most of the recommended trick on post, such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79684/fix-terminal-after-displaying-a-binary-file) one, and other similar to that, which fail to reset the cursor to it's initial state (eg: stay invisible)

Any recommended way to reset the state of the cursor, without closing/reopening the terminal?

Comment: Just **`tput cnorm`** affects the *cursor*.

Comment: YEP, work perfectly! @ThomasDickey

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just

```
tput cnorm
```

affects the cursor.

The *reset* command may not alter that, depending on the terminal description.  It's not an explicit step done by [*`reset`*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h3-reset---reinitialization), but rather something that is usually done for completeness (see [`tput reset`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h3-Commands) also).  If the terminal description used a **hard** reset, then (depending on the terminal emulator...) one would expect the terminal to restore the cursor.  However, **soft** resets are preferred, and those may/may not touch all of the aspects that a **hard** reset does.